# How to use the WebBrowser class from MonoDevelop

Tags: mono, web, browser, monodevelop

How can I use the Mono WebBrowser class in c#, I read this a thousand times and still can't get it.
I want to create an app with an embedded browser, in Ubuntu, using monodevelop.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into a external browser library like WebKit.Net? http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -1):

The WebBrowser class doesn't belong to the Mono namespace, but to System.Windows.Forms: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx

This doesn't mean that it cannot run on Mono though. It means that you can simply code your application in VisualStudio using MSDN as a reference (in case you don't understand how to do it from MonoDevelop), and then try to run your .exe with Mono directly.

That being said, I heard the WebBrowser backend in Mono was using Gecko API, and this API has been broken lately, so it may not work if you're using a very new Linux distribution.

Just test it and let us know.